# Playsound in C++: File error with .wav file

Tags: c++, sdl, wav, playsound

I'm copypasting and then tinkering with various examples of PlaySound in order to figure out how to play a .wav file in a C++ program.

Right now I have one that appears to work more than any of the others, but when the file executes it doesn't play the .wav file and inside the window it tells me there is a File error with the .wav file.

To reiterate: the program builds and runs no problem. It is within the running program that the error appears. I can't quite figure out what the issue is. Could it simply be a location problem?

The error says: "Wave::file error: drake.wav"

I've set up SDL, though it's possible I've done that incorrectly. I used the guide on [Lazyfoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php). I'm using Codeblocks and MinGW.

Here's the code, which I found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/88542/):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Wave {

public:
    Wave(char * filename);
    ~Wave();
    void play(bool async=true);
    bool isok();

private:
    char * buffer;
    bool ok;
    HINSTANCE HInstance;
};

Wave::Wave(char * filename)
{
    ok = false;
    buffer = 0;
    HInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);

    ifstream infile(filename, ios::binary);

    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cout << "Wave::file error: " << filename << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    infile.seekg (0, ios::end);
    int length = infile.tellg();
    buffer = new char[length];
    infile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    infile.read (buffer, length);

    infile.close();
    ok = true;
}

Wave::~Wave()
{
    PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0);
    delete [] buffer;
}

void Wave::play(bool async)
{
    if (!ok)
        return;

    if (async)
        PlaySound(buffer, HInstance, SND_MEMORY | SND_ASYNC);
    else
        PlaySound(buffer, HInstance, SND_MEMORY);
}

bool Wave::isok()
{
    return ok;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Trying to play sound...\n";

    Wave one("drake.wav");

    one.play();

    std::cout << "press key to exit";
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Thanks everyone for your help. It took me a while to figure this out.

Here's what I did:

1) I placed the .wav file inside the root folder.
2) I went to:
Project
Properties
Project's Build Options
Search Directories
Resource Compiler

and I placed the location of the file in the Resource Compiler.

**

Comment: Yes, it could be a file location problem. Remember (or learn!) that Code::Blocks **runs your executable with the project's root directory as the current directory**. Running an exe from windows explorer (or the linux equiv) runs the program with **it's folder as the current directory**. The current directory is used when opening a file and you have either (0) not specified a full path or (1) not specified a relative path.

Comment: Also, the WAV format is pretty simple and, if you've read Petzold's book, you'll see that using the sound hardware is fairly straight forward. About 200 lines of code allows you to read the file from disk and send it to the sound-card yourself. Naturally, you have _far_ greater control than what PlaySound affords you. Like for instance, the ability to play sounds that do not exist on disk, or to speed-up/slow-down the playback speed. Recording a musical note then changing the playback rate alters the pitch (and the duration, unfortunately) There's much fun to be had with sound. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a check in your code:

```
ifstream infile(filename, ios::binary);
if (!infile)
{
    std::cout << "Wave::file error: " << filename << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

So, it seems that the problem is simple: file not found. It means that this question is not about `PlaySound`, but about opening of a file.

You need to use full path (something like `Wave one("c:\\project\\drake.wav");`) or put wav-file right in the directory of the program (if you run the program from IDE, the current path of the program might be a little unexpected to you - not a path to executible file, but a path to a project file or something like this).